# Need to move files from VM and put into storage explorer - Azure

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

Every day at 8am we have files generated inside a VM that only I can access. I want to get those files automatically uploaded to a storage account that everyone can access, after they have been generated. How is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure file sync (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-deployment-guide) is the answer to this problem.

File Sync allows you to replicate files between a storage account and a file share on a VM.

By running this, you will be able to have your files generates on a share, have them replicated to a storage account and then either RBAC, SAS token or storage keys will allow your users to access the copies on the storage account.